Partition wall loading on parallel joist
I want to move a non-bearing 2nd floor bathroom wall about 2.5 feet to make the space bigger for a bathroom remodel . The wall is currently over a matching bathroom below so the walls previously carried through to the foundation.
The wall is 5.5 feet long and the ideal location would place one side 4 inches from a 2x10 joist running parallel to the wall. The underlying joist span is the same 5.5 feet. I calculated the wall weight with tile and all at about 390 lbs, or 8.8 psf, 70 plf. Adding blocks between the joists to bolster the 3/4” plywood wood take a lot of work but it would not be hard to move it over closer to, or on top of a joist. Not sure how the wall dead load gets distributed, and if I am safe.
Would either location work and will the joist(s) support this extra dead load?

When framing second (top) story partition walls, carpenters generally don't concern themselves with position relative to joists. Especially with such a small wall I don't have much concern--3/4" OSB or plywood subfloor is considered up to the task.
That said, I have a long (~16') partition wall in my home, which happens to have a vaulted ceiling above it (and therefore a vertical extension), which did sag the 3/4" OSB subfloor over time, being located dead center between joists on 19.2" intervals. I recently blocked below it to prevent further sag and attempt to remedy the dip during flooring replacement. I ended up using some floor patch to level it.
The point is that in most cases it's not at all an issue, but there are extreme non-bearing cases where blocking is well advised.

Sounds like there are schools of thought regarding blocking or not, but load should not be a concern. I saw someone saying code says no further than 4” from a joist, but my building authority said these house are built to accommodate 40 psf and did not see a problem, but tile walls are nearly double the weight of a Sheetrock wall. Can anyone say how I would calculate the distributed load in psf? If I decide to stay in the optimal location between joints that means I just screw the bottom plate to the plywood with 3 inch SDWS screws?

@popham, your skills are required forthwith.

The bottom plate can be fastened with about any screws or nails you have on hand. They're usually just shot down with the framing gun.

Personally, I would be more comfortable with blocking between the joists, even if I have to cut a hole in the subfloor to access (assuming no access from below).  The weight of a wall isn't insignificant, even if it's not load-bearing, especially once you load it with tile (although no indication if this is the case).
